# Python not parsing JSON correctly all the time. 

Tags: python, json, api, automation

Getting this back from a JSON object:

The call is made here:

```
response = make_request(GET_QUALIFIED_OFFERS_URL, request)

def make_request(url, json_data):
    host = url
    req = urllib2.Request(host, json_data, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
    response_stream = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    return response_stream.read()

response = {"Violations":[],"Messages":[],"Log":[],"Session":{"SessionId":813982132},"W3iDeviceId":294294043,"IsAfppOfferwallEnabled":true}, skipkeys=True, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4}

print json.dumps((response), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Getting an error:

```
print json.dumps({"Violations":[],"Messages":[],"Log":[],"Session":{"SessionId":813982132},"W3iDeviceId":294294043,"IsAfppOfferwallEnabled":true}, skipkeys=True, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
NameError: global name 'true' is not defined
```

It looks like some of the JSON isn't correct.  I put quotes around the value "true" and it works.  So is there any way to put quotes around all the values?

This Works:

```
response = {"Violations":[],"Messages":[],"Log":[],"Session":{"SessionId":813982132},"W3iDeviceId":294294043,"IsAfppOfferwallEnabled":"true"}, skipkeys=True, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, indent=4}
```

The problem is I have JSON like this all over the place with values like false and true with no quotes in huge key--value data sets.

What I am trying to do is take the JSon and make it pretty to be able to compare against it.  I am trying to write an automation frame work to test what comes back in the Json.  Ideally I would love to create like a csv ouput.  Maybe have a column for each key and then have a row for each value.  Anyone else doing something like this?

Comment: Try with True instead of true.

Answer (score 7):

In Python the keyword is `True`, not `true`.  Case sensitivity counts.  By way of example usage for both `dumps` and `loads`:

```
>>> from json import dumps, loads
>>>
>>> d1 = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': True, 'key3': False}
>>> s1 = dumps(d1)
>>> d2 = loads(s1)
>>> d1
{'key3': False, 'key2': True, 'key1': 'val1'}
>>> s1
'{"key3": false, "key2": true, "key1": "val1"}'
>>> d2
{u'key3': False, u'key2': True, u'key1': u'val1'}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That explains it.  So here is the issue.  I can't control that.  This is what I get back from the JSON object.  Is there a way to parse through the data and fix it?  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user1601701 - I think you're misunderstanding something.  What you've pasted _cannot_ be what you get back from the JSON Object.  If you have JSON it should be a string and `true` will be in lower case.  If you're working with a python dictionary `True` will be in upper case.  The dumps/loads methods account for this.  Your code, as posted, is simply wrong.  It appears as though someone attempted to take JavaScript Code and paste it directly into a .py file.

Comment: @user1601701 - Please review the edits I've made. It may clarify things for you.

Answer (score 4):

There's difference between writing pure JSON-string and converting a Python data structure into JSON-string.

Python's `JSON{En,De}coder` performs following translations by default:

```
JSON            Python

object          dict
array           list
string          unicode
number (int)    int, long
number (real)   float
true            True
false           False
null            None
```

So when you write `{'foo': True}` in Python, JSONEncoder writes out `{'foo': true}` as per JSON-standard.

Comment: I changed my code to do this:def make_request(url, json_data):
    host = url
    req = urllib2.Request(host, json_data, {'content-type': 'application/json'})
    response_stream = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    
    #this was a try to get the JSON formatted pretty---ran into issues with the JSON 
    data_obj = json.loads(response_stream.read())
    s = json.dumps(data_obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print s

    return response_stream.read()

Comment: This answer is really important. if you're importing data and the incoming string is `'{"data":False}'` python's json library will fail on `loads`. If you find this bug clean up the JSON first and register a bug with the JSON provider.