# Why can't I use true/false/null in a Python object fed to json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json

- I'm tring to decode(I think that's the right word) JSON to convert true, false, null to True, False, None for python
- I know I need the `json` library
- I followed [this thread's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11977844/4462930) but it didn't get me anywhere.
- I still receive the same error:
  `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`

...

```
import json

raw_json = {
'a':'aa',
'b':'bb',
'c':'cc',
'd':true,
'e':false,
'f':null
}

json_dump = json.dumps(raw_json)
json_load = json.loads(json_dump)
```

What am I doing wrong/need to do?

Also, I'm coming from a javascript background so it has been a pain trying to learn the conventions and terms. What are the 'u's prepending each json key in the other thread's link following 'd2'?

Comment: `true` is not a valid identifier for Python. `true` is valid for Javascript, for Python it is `True`

Comment: `raw_json` isn't actually JSON; it's just a Python `dict` object. `json_dump` would be the JSON (a text string conforming to ECMA-404 that represents a data structure). `json_load` is the Python object represented by `json_dump`.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for that clarification

Comment: @mic4ael, I am aware - as stated in the first bullet
My understanding was that the json module was able to convert it for me, is that not so?

Comment: @HanniAbu, no that is simply a `syntax` error. The library can't do anything about that. Your goal is to parse Python valid identifiers to JS valid tokens

Comment: @mic4ael, from the link below it seems as if the library is used to convert the value from 'true' to 'True'
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977818/python-not-parsing-json-correctly-all-the-time/11977844#11977844

Comment: Since the object fed to `dumps` needs to be a valid Python object, you need to describe it in the Python language, thus using `True` vs `true`. If you want to be able to write something in JSON, not in Python, then you need to put it in a string, and use `loads()` to parse that string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, exactly.

Comment: @HanniAbu, yes, but it takes the `true` **as part of a string passed to `loads()`**; it can't be used as a Python literal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I am getting this data on the fly so I can't hard code the booleans in there. Do I have any options besides setting the following?
true = True, false = False, nul = None

Comment: ...how are you getting data **as a literal in your module** on the fly? Most means of getting data on the fly mean you would be getting it as a string instead.

Comment: ...if you read from a file or from a network, then what you have is a string, not a literal, so your sample code does not represent your real situation.

Comment: ...which is to say: `raw_json = open('in.json', 'r').read()` does **not** result in the same behavior as your sample code here, even if the contents of `in.json` exactly matches what you gave in your question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ahhhh, okay! Yes this is what I am doing and needed that clarification. I was testing this seperate which now makes sense. Thank you for your patience Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed your raw JSON in code if you do so in a string (which, if you're using good practices to read data from disk or network, is what you'll have anyhow):

```
# similar to what you'd get from raw_json=open('in.json', 'r').read()
raw_json = '''{
'a':'aa',
'b':'bb',
'c':'cc',
'd':true,
'e':false,
'f':null
}'''

python_struct = json.loads(raw_json)
json_again = json.dumps(raw_json)
```

Because `true`, `false` and `null` are all inside of the string, the parser doesn't try to read them as valid Python, so `json.loads()` is able to see them as they were originally written.

Answer (score 5):

In your JSON variable `raw_json`, you need to capitalize `True` and `False`. In Python, Boolean values are capitalized for true and false. When you serialize it into JSON, they will be lower cased. Also, `None` is the Python equivalent of `null`.

When you perform a JSON dump, you are taking in a Python dictionary (which must be valid Python) and outputting a string which follows the JSON standard. The conversion visually changes the upper cased True, False, and None into their JSON equivalents true, false, and null.

To answer why there are `u`s on the strings, that is referring to the strings being Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you need `True`, `False`, and `None`.

```
raw_json = {
    'a':'aa',
    'b':'bb',
    'c':'cc',
    'd': True,
    'e': False,
    'f': None
}
```

Comment: I knew that, but from what I understood was that the json library could do that for me, no?

Comment: It can, but you're going in the wrong direction. `true` as an unquoted keyword in a JSON object can be converted by `json.loads` to the Python literal `True`.

Comment: So it can only do keywords and not values? In the following it is shown that the values can be converted

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977818/python-not-parsing-json-correctly-all-the-time/11977844#11977844

Comment: They are being converted, yes. But the converted form is no longer Python, it is now a string.

Answer (score 0):

Coming in late for an answer, but here is my take: you could just write raw_json as:

```
raw_json = {
    'a':'aa',
    'b':'bb',
    'c':'cc',
    'd':bool(1),
    'e':bool(0),
    'f':None
           }
```

"None" is the equivalent of null. And the boolean function helps create the your "true" and "false" for you.